# Student Visa NZ

Tags: visas, new-zealand

I had got the rejection for Canada twice, I had applied for New Zealand student visa. Will it create any problem in getting the visa ? Please tell me how to face such questions

Comment: Have you already applied?  "...had applied for newzealand student visa..."

Answer (score 1):

Canada and New Zealand have different visa rules, but they share plenty of information and they have *broadly speaking* the same concerns.

- Do they think you might violate the terms of your visa, e.g. overstay or work full time on a student visa?
- Do they think you are a political extremist?

If Canadians officials decided to reject your application, either the application was incomplete/badly written or your personal situation gave cause for concern. Has your situation changed since then? If not, NZ might reject your application for similar reasons as Canada. That doesn't mean NZ will refuse you a visa *because* Canada did.